# Delete specific element from array with innerHTML javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I need to make a simple project in javascript, we need to create a single library with javascript objects and let the user to add new books. I requested user data with a form tag in html and created new objects and I stored them inside a single array called library. The books are showed with no problem in the DOM the thing is that I need a button that deletes an specific book, I created a single button but it only deletes the first book in the array. I hope you can help me.

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Library</h1>
    <input id="title" type="text" placeholder="Book Title">
    <input id="author" type="text" placeholder="Book Author">
    <input id="date" type="text" placeholder="Publish Date">

    <select id="read" name="read">
      <option value="yes">yes</option>
      <option value="no">no</option>
    </select> 

    <input type="button" value="New Book" onclick="add_book()">

    <div id="display"></div>
  
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


JAVASCRIPT:

var library = [];

var title_input = document.getElementById("title");
var author_input = document.getElementById("author");
var date_input = document.getElementById("date");
var read_input = document.getElementById("read");

function Book(title, author, date, read) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.date = date
    this.read = read
};

function add_book() {
    var newBook = new Book(title_input, author_input, date_input, read_input)
    library.push(`Title: ${newBook.title.value} <br>`+`Author: ${newBook.author.value} <br>`+
    `Realease date: ${newBook.date.value} <br>`+`Readed: ${newBook.read.value} <br>` )
    show_library(); 
};

function delete_book(arr, elem){
    index = arr.indexOf(elem);
    arr.splice(elem,1);
    show_library(); 
}

function show_library() {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "";
    for(i = 0; i<library.length; i++){
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += library[i]+
        '<button onclick="delete_book(library, library[i]);">Delete</button><br>';
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You've written `library[i]` as plain text into the DOM. This doesn't references the variable `i` from your loop.

You can simply write the index as argument and use this directly in your function `delete_book`.

```js
var library = [];

var title_input = document.getElementById("title");
var author_input = document.getElementById("author");
var date_input = document.getElementById("date");
var read_input = document.getElementById("read");

function Book(title, author, date, read) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.date = date
    this.read = read
};

function add_book() {
    var newBook = new Book(title_input, author_input, date_input, read_input)
    library.push(`Title: ${newBook.title.value} <br>`+`Author: ${newBook.author.value} <br>`+
    `Realease date: ${newBook.date.value} <br>`+`Readed: ${newBook.read.value} <br>` )
    show_library(); 
};

function delete_book(arr, index){
    arr.splice(index, 1);
    show_library(); 
}

function show_library() {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "";
    for(i = 0; i<library.length; i++){
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += library[i]+
        `<button onclick="delete_book(library, ${i});">Delete</button><br>`;
    }
};
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Library</h1>
    <input id="title" type="text" placeholder="Book Title">
    <input id="author" type="text" placeholder="Book Author">
    <input id="date" type="text" placeholder="Publish Date">

    <select id="read" name="read">
      <option value="yes">yes</option>
      <option value="no">no</option>
    </select> 

    <input type="button" value="New Book" onclick="add_book()">

    <div id="display"></div>
  
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```